# Confused about CMake's cached variable setting priority

Tags: caching, cmake

I'm confused about CMake's cached variables:

- Case 1: `CACHE` + `FORCE`

  ```
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "myflags" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
  ```

  - **First CMake run:** `"myflags"` appears in the `CMakeCache.txt` file as intended.
  - **Command line options:** command line options do not override `"myflags"` - seems like `FORCE` has higher priority than command line `-D...="..."` arguments. This is not desired - I would like command line arguments to override `"myflags"`.

---

- Case 2: only `CACHE`

  ```
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "myflags" CACHE STRING "")
  ```

  - **First CMake run:** nothing appears in the `CMakeCache.txt` file. I want`"myflags"` to appear for the first run.
  - **Command line options:** command line have priority over `"myflags"`.

---

**Am I correct about my conclusions? Or do "default variables" such as `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` behave differently?**

**Is there a way to have `"myflags"` written in the `CMakeCache.txt` file during the first CMake run (when CMake wasn't run previously in this folder)?**

I'd like to set `"myflags"` during the first CMake run in the cache, then allow the user to override it using the command line.

If I use `FORCE`, the user can't override it via command line.

If I don't use `FORCE`, `"myflags"` isn't written in the cache file during the first run.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is consistent with the behaviour explained in the [documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/set.html):

> Normally, set(...CACHE...) creates cache variables, but does not modify them. If FORCE is specified, the value of the cache variable is set, even if the variable is already in the cache. This should normally be avoided, as it will remove any changes to the cache variable’s value by the user.

`CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` is present in the cache even without `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ... CACHE ...)` in your CMakeLists.txt, because `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` variable is already set during compiler flags initialization.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I understand now. One more thing: how would you suggest me to implement the behavior I desire? (Filling `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` on first run, then allowing the user to override them.) Should I check if the variable is empty and fill it in that case?

Comment: What about using different variable for custom CXX flags (e.g. `MYFLAGS`) and merging it SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}  ${MYFLAGS}"`?